# Do PHP sessions get lost when directing to a payment gateway?

Tags: php

If i was to store some order details in a session whilst the customer is redirected to a payment gateway, would they be lost by the time the custom returns back from the gateway?

My plan is:

website take order -> store order in session -> website goes to paypal -> payment made -> returns using paypal autoreturn to confirmation page -> on return get session order data and submit to database.

Comment: not unless they have cookies disabled

Comment: ? they will be ok if i have cookies as well?

Comment: you could use either a cookie or a session.  sessions always expire when the browsers closes, cookies you can ask to expire at some future time.

Comment: Cookies and session can and will both expire (Murphy's Law). Use the return URL feature that payment providers (including PayPal) provide for _exactly_ this reason. See my detailed explanation below.

Comment: To elaborate on Abel's statement. Sessions don't expire when you close the browser, the browser simply assumes a new session_id. The session is still there on the server until it truly expires. Cookies are controlled by the browser so in reality they can expire whenever the browser feels like it. Which simply said means that you can not reliably use either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how long it takes them to come back to your site. I don't know what the default expire time is for sessions but you can assume it to be anywhere from a few minutes to a few hours.

If you want to assure the user gets to see whatever he needs to, you will need the payment gateway to redirect the user to a URL that you specify. For instance:

/payment.php?status=complete&receipt=875628dwf87sdfsg785623

Where the receipt identifies anything you want it to: the user, the transaction, both?

Most payment gateways support such a feature. If yours does not, contact your payment gateway.

**If you want to show them a receipt, do not use sessions or cookies, use the return URL method I describe.**

Comment: I have added what i wish to do to the post.

Comment: Yes, then this is exactly what you need. How are you interfacing with PayPal? With a button or with a form?

Comment: So i store as a session and then on return read the session and store. Is this better than using Payment Data Transfer? guessins this is what you were saying above?

Comment: No, do not use sessions to store the order (at least not for this step). When a user returns from PayPal the session (or cookie) may have expired. You need to use the return URL feature.

Comment: I can not stress this enough. DO NOT USE SESSION OR COOKIES for this step.

Comment: Contact PayPal merchant support if you're unsure how to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will use there data return url, and store the order details in that, so when if the payment returns i can access the. :)

Answer (score 6):

I found the problem.

Paypal redirect back client to yoursite.com without the www.

cookies on `http://www.yoursite.com` are `http://yoursite.com` are not considered the same.

To fix that, add .htaccess to your www root;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/www\.yoursite\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Session *may* be lost if visitor was in HTTP when leaving and comes back as HTTPS (or vice-versa)

Answer (score 2):

Sessions won't get "lost" as long as your server supports session cookies, but they may **expire**.

Answer (score 1):

The session is an ID to identify the session and the data belonging to the session. The data is stored on your server as long as you like. The ID is either saved as a cookie or handled as a GET-parameter which should be avoided generally. If you have the ID saved in a cookie then there is no reason why another site should interfere with it.

So I see no reason why your session should be lost.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the customer has cookies enabled in their browser, the session will remain when they return, unless they've closed their browser window first.  Sessions IDs are kept in a cookie, which expires when the browser closes.

You could also, if you wanted to, keep the information in a cookie, though this would be less preferable if there was any private information you needed to be kept.

***EDIT***
also, the answer about creating a session in HTTPS then accessing it again in HTTP is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The session remains active as per your application's session expiry settings.

The new versions of the browsers might be destroying the session because of the new cookie policy.

References
https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/01/get-ready-for-new-samesitenone-secure
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Whenever the cookie is required to be sent to server, the browser sees the SameSite attribute to decide if the cookie to be sent to server or blocked. For user actions, it is sent to the server but for auto-redirects, it doesn't if SameSite is set to 'Strict' or 'Lax' (Lax is going to be the default value now).

Solution:

The cookie attribute SameSite can be set to 'None' along with specifying the 'Secure' attribute to 'true'. Setting 'Secure' attribute to 'true' would require your site to run on https. Sites running with http:// protocol will not be able to set 'Secure' cookie.
Please set the 'HttpOnly' attribute to 'true' for making it accessible for http requests to the server only.

In PHP, it can be achieved as below

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/PATH/; SameSite=None', <COOKIE_DOMAIN>, true, true);