# Cookies being deleted on redirect

Tags: php, cookies

I have a problem with cookies.

Basically I'm trying to store the user's session ID as a cookie like so:

```
 setcookie("CheckoutSessionID",session_id(),time()+3600);
```

This works fine on my site, the cookie has the correct value and is valid for long enough. However, my site redirects to PayPal so the user can confirm a payment. The user is then redirected back to my site. It's when the user is redirected back to my site that ALL cookie variables are gone.

As in, `print_r($_COOKIE)`, `var_dump($_COOKIE)` etc have no values. This only occurs after being directed to and from PayPal.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance for all help, I'm stumped!

Comment: what's the function `session_id()` returning?

Comment: and when you are echoing, use `echo $_COOKIE["CheckoutSessionId"]`

Comment: session_id() is returning the correct session ID and I'm able to output $_COOKIE["CheckoutSessionID"] just fine on all my pages right after I've set the cookie. 

However, as soon as the user is redirected from PayPal, ALL cookies are gone.

Comment: Also, this isn't just a problem with returning to that one particular page, this also occurs if you cancel the PayPal input and get returned to another, very basic page on the site. All cookies are gone again.

Comment: Sounds a little bit mad. Is the page paypal is redirecting back to on the same domain?

Comment: Both pages you can be redirected to from PayPal are on the same domain as the page which sets the cookies and the pages which can access the cookie data also...

Comment: Remember there is a difference between **https** and **http**, as in, they are different domains for the cookie. If your checkout page is ssl secured, the redirect to paypal happens, and paypal redirects to a non ssl secured page, that could be the reason why the cookie is being lost.

Comment: None of my site pages are SSL secured, I haven't read anywhere that this was a requirement for PayPal integration (as my site doesn't handle any important data whatsoever). Would this really be a reason for all cookies for my site to be deleted though? I didn't think redirecting to another site could affect them like this.

Comment: No, unless you switch between ssl and no ssl you shouldn't see those problems. It's odd then...

Comment: Oh, by the way, if you set a cookie and redirect on the same request the cookie will not be properly set; could that be the problem?

Comment: That's not the problem because I'm setting the cookie on one page, the user has to click a button to go to another page which redirects them to PayPal. On all these pages, cookies work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I've been digging quite deep and realised that an earlier question of mine is related:

[PHP sessions and session_start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803978/php-sessions-and-session-start)

Basically I had problems because PHP sessions were being deleted when I went to PayPal and back. However, I believe this was actually caused by the session COOKIE being destroyed, not the entire session.

I also found this topic here: [Do PHP sessions get lost when directing to a payment gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218608/do-php-sessions-get-lost-when-directing-to-a-payment-gateway)

Answer given by someone suggests using a GET request with the return URL to send data back, instead of using cookies or sessions.

The whole reason I was using a cookie in the first place was to save the user's session ID, as the sessions weren't working properly, so basically I've just made my return URL something like this:

mydomain.co.uk/mypage.php?SessionID=[session ID goes here] and then obtained it then set the user's session ID to it.

Sorted! For now... I mean I'll probably end up hitting another brick wall due to cookies/sessions not working properly.

Thanks everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually whatever is happening (cookie is being empty), logically it's right. When you submit a page/make request the browser sends the `cookie` from the client's computer with the request so that you can find the `cookie` in the `cookie` variable.

But once you redirect the user to another external page/site and come back again to your page then you should not get the `cookie` in the `cookie` variable because (in your case) when the user is getting back to your site from the `paypal` the `paypal` is not submitting the `cookie` with the request.

In this case you can save your data in the database before you redirect the user to the `paypal` and once the user comes back to your site you can retrieve that data from the database.

Comment: Can you tell if its the same user - send a particular cookie to a particular user?

Answer (score 1):

I got similar problem cookies being removed after redirect from Paypal.

it took me a while to figure out where was a problem.

```
Samesite=**"Strict"** // Removes cookies after redirect from Paypal.

Samesite=**"Lax"** // does not remove cookies after redirect from Paypal.
```